# get_post_thumbnail_id() Doesn't return value

Tags: post-thumbnails, thumbnails

I'm changing a menu from a loop with `query_posts` to a "custom menu" using `wp_get_nav_menu_items`, but I can't seem to retrieve the `post_thumbnail`.

The original code I had (snippet):

```
<?php
query_posts($args);
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id());
endwhile; endif;?>
```

My new code:

```
<?php
$menu = wp_get_nav_menu_items('Homepage blokken');
foreach($menu AS $m){
     echo $m->ID; // this echoes the correct ID
     $pThumbId = get_post_thumbnail_id($m->ID); // this returns empty
} ?>
```

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dammit, I just discovered that the `$m->ID` I was using wasn't actually the `post->ID`, but the `menu->ID`. I used `$m->object_id` to fix the issue. Hope this will help someone in the future `:-S`

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code, you will get the exact output:

```
foreach ( $items as $el ) {
    if ( $el->post_parent == $parent ) {
        array_push( 
            $ret,
            array(
                'id'   => $el->object_id,
                'text' => $el->title,
                'url'  => $el->url
            )
        );
    }
}
```